# How can I re-query post_type and rewrite the url?

Tags: wp-query, url-rewriting, pre-get-posts

I have the url slush like the below.

/category/land-residential-farm/?property_com_listing_type=sale

I want to write the url to

/category/land-residential-farm/property-for-sale

then re-query the post for sale meta data.

Anyone please kindly point the way

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to first define `property_com_listing_type` as a query:

- https://codepen.io/the_ruther4d/post/custom-query-string-vars-in-wordpress

Then you can rewrite the urls with `add_rewrite_rule` (do not forget to save permalinks after change):

- https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

with a regex like `^category/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?`

Then you can modify the query using `pre_get_posts`:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helps me a lot, but I have problem with url rewrite. Here is the code:

function custom_rewrite_basic() {
 add_rewrite_rule('^category/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?', 'index.php?post_type=commercial&location=$matches[1]&property_com_listing_type=$matches[2]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic', 10, 0);

page not found.

/category/land-residential-farm/property-for-sale

Comment: Use `category_name=$matches[1]` instead of `location=$matches[1]`. And how does your `pre_get_posts` look ?